# check if file is empty or not

Tags: unix

How do I check if a file is empty in a korn script

I want to test in my korn script if the output CSV file is empty or not  and if it is not empty then it should give the count of values.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a file is empty in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964823/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-empty-in-bash)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`test(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) program has a `-s` switch:

```
-s FILE
      FILE exists and has a size greater than zero
```

Comment: thank you!But this -s File name will not give the exact of count of records.

Comment: @user2260271 Yup, this only answers the question "find out if file is non empty".

Comment: Thanks...Actually i need the count for the records available in the file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by count of values.  Your other comment suggests that you're looking for number of records, in which case, you can try: `cat csv-file | wc -l`.

Comment: i want to check CSV file whether it is empty or not and if it is "not empty" then it should give the count of Records. Thanks.

Comment: How to remove the footer value also?in this function

Comment: How do I check if a csv file is empty or not without counting header and footer value.

Comment: @user2260271 It may be time to get some better tool for the job, like `python` or something that understands csv.

Answer (score -1):

This is just another way of doing it, albeit a roundabout one:

```
if [ `ls -l <file> | awk '{print $5}'` -eq 0 ]
then
//condition for being empty
else
//condition for not being empty
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if [ ! -f manogna.txt ]
then
    echo "  Error: manogna.txt  does not exist  "
else
    echo " manogna.txt   exist " 
    echo " no of records in manogna.txt are `cat manogna.txt   | wc -l`"
fi
```